# MySQL: Select multiple max values from one column

Tags: mysql

Suppose I got this table:

**mytable**

> ```
> +------+-------+
> | type | count |
> +------+-------+
> | red  | 4     |
> | blue | 3     |
> | red  | 2     |
> | blue | 7     |
> +------+-------+
> ```

Now I want this back:

> ```
> +--------+---------+
> | maxRed | maxBlue |
> +--------+---------+
> | 4      | 7       |
> +--------+---------+
> ```

How can I do this?

This is what I tried

```
SELECT MAX(count) as maxRed, 0 as maxBlue FROM mytable WHERE type='red'

UNION

SELECT 0 as maxRed, MAX(count) as maxBlue FROM mytable WHERE type='blue'
```

but it does not quite work and only results

> ```
> +--------+---------+
> | maxRed | maxBlue |
> +--------+---------+
> | 4      | 0       |
> | 0      | 7       |
> +--------+---------+
> ```

Comment: People claim here that my solutions sucks , however I tested it and for a large table it's faster.I am voted -4. This is unfair ! will you run a benchmark of the solutions and do me justice.

Comment: FWIW, I think a *better* solution is to handle issues of data display in application level code - e.g. a simple PHP loop.

Comment: Also, your table lacks a primary key - which can prove problematic if and when it comes to dealing with relational data.

Comment: @Strawberry in my real world problem I do have a much larger table including a primary key. I forgot to mention the primary key here, because I wanted to reduce the problem amap - sorry about it. Not sure why you prefere a PHP loop here. fancyPants solution is a much better SQL query then the one that I had. In this case the sql query takes less time and the code is shorter and better readible. I do not know what more you could ask for :P.

Comment: A presentation-layer solution would far more flexible, and scalable - without any loss of performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to do it:

```
SELECT
MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'red' THEN `count` ELSE NULL END) AS maxRed,
MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'blue' THEN `count` ELSE NULL END) AS maxBlue
FROM
mytable
WHERE type IN ('red', 'blue');
```

Comment: Sorry you still apply the condition twice to the records.I my solution you only go each time over the records you really need

Comment: You select all records red of blue and apply your condition to each line.I only select for each sum the lines I need. Think about it , really.

Comment: I don't see, how this makes your query faster, sorry.

Comment: @O_Z Stop misleading people. Read before commenting. You are wrong and that's the best approach for this kind of question.

Answer (score 7):

For your query to work you only needed to wrap it with another query:

```
SELECT MAX(maxRed) as maxRed, MAX(maxBlue) as maxBlue
FROM(
    SELECT MAX(count) as maxRed, 0 as maxBlue FROM mytable WHERE type='red'
    UNION
    SELECT 0 as maxRed, MAX(count) as maxBlue FROM mytable WHERE type='blue') t
```

A more elegant way is conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN t.type = 'red' THEN t.count END) as maxRed,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.type = 'blue' THEN t.count END) as maxBlue
FROM mytable t
WHERE t.type IN('blue','red')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT type,MAX(count) FROM mytable group by type
```

This will return type and maxcount in vertical and not horizontal and is scalable for n number of records.

If horizontal data doesn't matter otherwise you can use above suggested answers to use case but it will require case when then for each distinct value of data.

Comment: Upvoting, because this is actually the prefered way. Cosmetic stuff should be done on application level. Should have at least mentioned it in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

***EDIT***
Because of the comments below I tested it on real data, my version is a bit faster for a large table ,when mytable is indexed. For those who argue about it please test yourself and report back.

```
 select 
(select max(count) from mytable  WHERE type='red') aa,
(select max(count) from mytable  WHERE type='blue') bb
```

Comment: No offense, but that's the least elegant way to do it.

Comment: @fancyPants Wrong!, This will not go create a full table scan, if you have many types and need only some of them.

Comment: No, he is not wrong. You are selecting twice from the table when only one time required .

Comment: I am selecting different recods each time, not going over the same ones  twice, you do.If we have an index for type my version is faster

Comment: No, it's not. If we have an index for type, my query benefits as well :)

Comment: Your version will never be better. The optimizer has no problem processing two columns at the same time. Read before you mislead people!

Comment: -4 is unfair, I ran benchmarks and tested my solution against other solutions. please supply a contradiction or up vote me.

Comment: @O_Z I will do a test in a few hours and check if your right. Offtopic: I did not like fancyPants language, I don't think he should be so rude to you.

Comment: @Adam Thanks, Just remember my solution works faster only if you have an index for the type field. This is not about points, but about checking facts and not being religious about programming.

Comment: How many rows are in your large testing table? I checked with a small table with about 700 rows and there seems to be no speed difference between your and the other solution (with or without indexing type)

Comment: @Adam my table was 500K records with an index. Anyway even in your test my solution is at leas not slower.

Comment: Yeah. I also understand that when type is indexed, that you dont go twice over the complete table (but you would if type is not an index). So your solution seems reasonable aslong type is an index. Also note that `fancyPants` added to his SQL `WHERE type IN ('red', 'blue');` so I think with that addition both SQL statments should have the same speed even on a 500K record table.

Comment: @Adam This difference is that in my solution there is no CASE WHEN for all the records selected.so you only sum what your need, so it's still a bit faster.